# Get intermediate array in Javascript Map function

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to get the array being generated by the map function, inside the map function? For e.g.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.map(item => {
  console.log(currentArray);
  return item * item;
}
```

So, in the above example, if at line 3 (currentArray), I want below output, how can I get that.

```
[1]
[1, 4]
[1, 4, 9]
```

The "array" parameter in map callback, returns the original array on which map function is called.
Or do I need to go conventional for loop route to achieve this?

Comment: Why not `array#reduce`?

Comment: Instead of using `.map()`, you could use `forEach` method. Declare an empty array which will hold the sub arrays and using `forEach`, iterate over the array, adding new sub array in each iteration.  `arr.forEach((num, i) => res[i] = i > 0 ? [...res[i-1], num * num] : [num*num]);
` P.S: `res` is initially an empty array that will contain the sub-arrays after `forEach` ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function as follow,

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];


arr.reduce((acc, item)=>{
   acc.push(item*item);
   console.log(acc);
   return acc;
}, []);



// SINCE YOU ARE ASKING HOW TO DO IT USING MAP
console.log('*******************************')

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const currentArray = [];
arr1.map(item => {
  currentArray.push(item * item);
  console.log(currentArray);
  return  item* item;
})
```

Comment: You can use the short version of `map & reduce` as show by other users. So I don't want to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could map the squares by using a closure over ta temporary result set.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    result = array.map((t => v => t = [...t, v * v])([]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That is defining `reduce` in terms of `map`. Excellent! I have learnt something. Thanks! You have been followed!

Comment: Ok, this is pretty interesting. I'll check this.

Comment: But if the asker wants really what s/he writes, it is just access to the t in every step, which your answer still satisfies. S/he was not specific about the return anyways.

Comment: I was wrong; `map` can be written in terms of `reduce` but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` instead of the `map`, but you do not have to by the way. Anyways, then you will have your accumulator as the first argument to the reducer callback. The variable `accumulator` will hold the intermediate states of the value to be returned.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let result = arr.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  console.log("currentArray accumulator: ", accumulator);
  return [...accumulator, item * item];
}, []);
```

There is a neat another answer around which uses `map` and do what you want. So, yes it is possible to achieve same with `map` and `reduce` is a convenience function that actually is a special case `map` function itself.

Comment: reducer, change to reduce

Comment: It does not, well at the end. I return a new array at every step of it. I could very well use push to not return a new array at every step. But at the end there is no three arrays

Comment: I tested it and it does not produce the desired output. I did not downvote you btw

Comment: I have tested as well. You must be wrong it does produce the desired output. Desired out put is as in the question to have intermediate arrays in the callback function and the `accumulator` is it.